# Prefect Server: No Tenant Found

Tags: python-3.x, prefect

I am attempting to spin up a Prefect Agent, in order to complete the setup with a Prefect Server. Rather than using `prefect server start` for out-of-the-box setup, I used `prefect server config` to generate the Docker Compose file and then `docker compose up` to spin up the server's services. When I tried to start the Agent, I got the following error:

```
prefect.utilities.exceptions.ClientError:
[{'message': 'No tenant found.', 
  'locations': [{'line': 2, 'column': 5}], 
  'path': ['register_agent'], 
  'extensions': {
    'code': 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', 
    'exception': {'message': 'No tenant found.'}
  }
}]
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Prefect CLI: `prefect backend server`, then `prefect server create-tenant -n default`

Using Prefect Server GraphQL API, as done in the [Prefect source code](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/blob/master/src/prefect/client/client.py#L111):

```
tenant_info = self.graphql(
            {
                "mutation($input: create_tenant_input!)": {
                    "create_tenant(input: $input)": {"id"}
                }
            },
            variables=dict(input=dict(name=name, slug=slug)),
        )
```